# How to set frame of NSTextFieldCell in NSTableView

Tags: objective-c, macos, nstableview, nstextfield

I am facing problem to set the frame of a `NSTextFieldCell` in Mac. My `NSTextFieldCell` is at (0,0) point of the Column. I need to 4px gap in y position. Below is the image of existing UI.

[image: Existing Column]

And here is the .xib structure looks like:

[image]

The delegate method under which I am trying to set the frame is as under:

```
- (void)tableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView willDisplayCell:(id)aCell forTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)aTableColumn row:(NSInteger)aRow
{
    if ([[aTableColumn identifier] isEqualToString:@"notes"])
    {
        [aCell setBackgroundColor:[NSColor redColor]];

        NSTextFieldCell *theCellView = aCell;
        NSView *controlView = [theCellView controlView];
        NSRect frame = controlView.frame;
        frame.origin.x = 120;
        frame.origin.y = 130;
        [controlView setFrame:frame];       
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the table view supposed to be view based or cell based?

Comment: Thanks @Willeke. It's cell based.

Comment: The controlView of the cell is the table view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cells don't have frames. Cells are lightweight objects that draw where the owning control view tells them. The table view may use a single cell to draw all of the rows of a given column. It will compute the frame of one row of the column, configure the cell with the value from that row and column, and tell the cell to draw itself in the frame it computed. Then, it will configure the cell for the next row and tell the cell to draw itself in that row's frame. Etc.

So, you need to concentrate on the table view, not the cell to influence the frame in which the cell draws, because it's the table view that's computing that frame. Have you tried setting the `intercellSpacing` to have a non-zero `height`?

Also, you should consider converting to a view-based table view where you have much greater control.

Comment: Thanks Ken. The app is already developed, so no scope of re-development. I will try intercellSpacing. Actually I need padding of 5px. Tried with NSMutableParagraph but no luck.